# RPi3 with SenseHat and Yocto

Tags: yocto, raspberry-pi3, openembedded

I am currently working with building a Yocto Image for the RPi3 with the SenseHat installed.

The Yocto image consist of the following layers:

- meta
- meta-poky
- meta-oe
- meta-networking
- meta-python
- meta-raspberrypi
- meta-java
- an application-specific layer.

The application-specific layer is mainly tasked with loading the following kernel-modules:

- i2c-dev
- fb_sys_fops
- syscopyarea
- sysfillrect
- sysimgblt
- rpisense_core
- rpisense_js
- rpisense_fb

It also contains openssh, psplash, gcc, make, libiio, rtimulib and some other misc. packages.

My image boots nicely without the SenseHat mounted, but the boot-process stops before reaching the UART shell when it is mounted. It stays frozen until the system is reset by the watchdog.

Following is the last part of the UART output before the system freezes.

```
{...}
Populating dev cache
ALSA: Restoring mixer settings...
/usr/sbin/alsactl: load_state:1735: No soundcards found...
Tue Nov  1 10:01:54 UTC 2016
INIT: Entering runlevel: 5
Configuring network interfaces... [    5.130327] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
udhcpc (v1.24.1) started
Sending discover...
[    6.662428] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x4DE1
[    6.688217] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Sending discover...
Sending select for 192.168.0.106...
Lease of 192.168.0.106 obtained, lease time 3600
/etc/udhcpc.d/50default: Adding DNS 192.168.0.20
/etc/udhcpc.d/50default: Adding DNS 192.168.0.40
done.
Starting system message bus: dbus.
Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd
[    9.034713] NET: Registered protocol family 10
done.
Starting rpcbind daemon...done.
Starting advanced power management daemon: No APM support in kernel
(failed.)
Starting bluetooth
bluetoothd
Starting syslogd/klogd: done
 * Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Daemon: avahi-daemon
[    9.401783] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[    9.405528] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[    9.410088] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    9.416576] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    9.421576] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    9.426747] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
   ...done.
Starting Telephony daemon
[    9.507315] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    9.512765] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    9.518098] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Starting Linux NFC daemon
[    9.624816] nfc: nfc_init: NFC Core ver 0.1
[    9.629241] NET: Registered protocol family 39
```

I shoould note that I have soldered three wires onto the UART pins:

[RPi3 UART pins http://www.embeddedforu.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Raspberry-pi-UART-connections_thumb.png](http://www.embeddedforu.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Raspberry-pi-UART-connections_thumb.png)

When the system is frozen, I can still ping the device, but SSH does not work.

Any idea what might be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem lay within the yocto **local.conf**-file. The following line was set:

```
ENABLE_I2C = "1"
```

This created a second i2c-driver, which lead to one of the crashing on boot.

For any googlers out there: This flag does not need to be set. Instead make sure that the **i2c-dev** kernel driver is loaded at boot.

Answer (score 0):

I never used the bluetooth, but it seems the system doesn't freeze, you just lose UART data when Bluetooth connects.
From [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/how-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3):
On the rpi3, it is normal since the BCM2837 on the Raspberry Pi3 has 2 UARTs (as did its predecessors), however to support the Bluetooth functionality the fully featured PL011 UART was moved from the header pins to the Bluetooth chip and the mini UART made available on header pins 8 & 10.

This has a number of consequences for users of the serial interface.

The /dev/ttyAMA0 previously used to access the UART now connects to Bluetooth.

I would advise you to try again having in config.txt

```
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
enable_uart=1
```

And if you really need bluetooth, use

```
dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt
```

And for the ssh, add "openssh" in your image recipe, and dependencies to connect like wpa-supplicant (don't forget to configure it)